# auto scroll to bottom directive doesn't work in angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I am creating a chat application where I need to implement auto-scroll to bottom of the text messages. div should be done on the initial load and reload of the page. I created a custom directive to implement this. However this doesn't seems to work.

directive:

```
import { Directive,ElementRef,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';


@Directive({ selector: '[scrollToBottom]' })
export class ScrollToBottomDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private element:ElementRef) {
        console.log('scroll', this.element);
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.scrollToBottom();
    }
    scrollToBottom(){
        if(this.element){
            (this.element as any).nativeElement.scrollTop =(this.element as any).nativeElement.scrollHeight;
            console.log('scroll', (this.element as any).nativeElement.scrollTop) 
            console.log('scrollHeight', (this.element as any).nativeElement.scrollHeight) 
        }
    }
}
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
ScrollToBottom() {
    if(this.element){
       // I can't remember why I added a short timeout, 
       // the below works great though. 
       if(this.element != undefined){
          setTimeout(() => { element.scrollIntoView(true) }, 200);
       }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the life cycle hook from 'AfterViewInit' to 'afterViewChecked' event

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you need to scroll bottom once, I recommend next solution:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewChecked, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollToBottom]'
})
export class ScrollToBottomDirective implements AfterViewChecked {
  isActive = true;

  @HostListener('scroll') onFrameScroll() {
    this.isActive = false;
  }

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }

  scrollToBottom() {
    if (this.element && this.isActive) {
      this.element.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.element.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    }
  }
}
```